# Is there a (preferable built-in) way to check what custom queries are used in a theme?

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, wp-query, customization, query

I've build a theme using custom post-types with queries like

```
$my_custom_post_type_query = new WP_Query( array( 'my_arg' => 'value' ));
```

Now I'm writing a plugin where I need to do something like

```
$wp_query->get_queried_object_id();
```

but for `$my_custom_post_type_query` instead of `$wp_query`.

**How can I** (from my plugin file)

1. check if there *are* any custom queries, and if so
2. call a specific custom query within my plugin?

Any ideas much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand what you're trying to do, so here goes nothing:

There are a lot of hooks within WP_Query. Most of them pass the current instance as one of the arguments. So, here's how you could check for a "custom query":

```
function check_wp_query( $posts, $wp_query ) {
  if ( $wp_query->get('my_arg') ) {
    // it's a custom query
  }

  return $posts;
}
add_filter( 'the_posts', 'check_wp_query', 10, 2 );
```

The trick is that each custom query has to be identifiable by at least one of it's query vars.

Comment: Would this also work if my query isn't named `$wp_query` but `$my_custom_post_type_query`?

Like  


`function check_wp_query( $posts, $my_custom_post_type_query ) {  
    if ( $my_custom_post_type_query->get('my_arg') ) {
    // it's a custom query
  }

  return $posts;
}
add_filter( 'the_posts', 'check_wp_query', 10, 2 );`
Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I have to find out how formatting works in comments… :-/

Comment: Bang, the last comment crashed my browser AND my user account on Mac OSX. Interesting.


Thanks a bunch anyway, Scribu. I'll go find out about those hooks before I ask more stupid questions. ;-)

Comment: It's a formal argument, so you can call it whatever you want. Not to be confused with `global $wp_query`.